# Hide selected option at dynamically form jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I need to achieve something like when a user selects an option from one select box the option should be hidden for the other select boxes. When a selected option changes the previously selected option should become available again to the other select boxes. But my code seem like only can work at the static selection box.

```js
var i = 0;
$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
  $('.s').change(function() {
    let value = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('.s').children('option').attr('disabled', false);
    $('.s').each(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.s').children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']').attr('disabled', 'disabled');

    })
  });
});

function addRow() {
  var tr = '<tr class="cb" id="row_' + i + '"><td>';
  tr += '<select class="s form-control select2" id="name1_' + i + ' first" name="name[]" >';
  tr += '<option id="1">tan</option><option id="2">lim</option><option id="3">vin</option><option id="4">alex</option></select></td>';
  tr += '<td><input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_' + i + '" class="form-control"></td>';
  tr += '<td style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>';
  tr += '</td></tr>';
  i++;
  $('tbody').append(tr);
}

$('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});

$('.savebtn').on('click', function() {
  $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item) {
    console.log($('#amt1_' + index).val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered listable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="text-center">
      <th>name</th>
      <th>amount</th>
      <th style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="text-center"></tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary savebtn">Save</button>
```

Comment: You want to filter the selected options from the other combo-boxes?

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow provides [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) (icon looks like `<>` in the editor toolbar) which provides an experience similar to jsFiddle, but here on Stack Overflow. If you use Stack Snippets, we don't have to ask you to provide things like the HTML that goes with the jQuery you've provided, or the CSS.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl ya, which means if the option has been selected, it will hide from other select boxes. One name only can select one time.

Comment: You could achieve such a thing with `$('select').change(function(){$('select option[value='+this.value+']').prop('disabled',true); $(this).children('option[value='+this.value+']').prop('disabled',false);});`

Comment: Here's updated version for all the requirements and adjusted to your code: `$('.s').change(function(){
$('.s option).show();
$('.s option[value='+this.value+']').hide(); $(this).children('option[value='+this.value+']').show();});`

Comment: @user3647971 Hi, seem like the selection still able to choose.

Comment: @MMMM You can swap the selections, disable them and hide them with same selectors. For example `$('.s').each(function(index){if($(this).val() == this.value){$('.s option').prop('selected',false);});` which unselects the ones which are of same value, then you can disable them: `$('.s option[value='+this.value+']').prop('disabled',true);$(this).children('option[value='+this.value+']').prop('disabled',false);`

Comment: @user3647971, can you help to write down the answer ya?

Comment: Sure I'll put it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution was to show and enable all everytime something changes then disable and hide all of the options with same value as the ones selected and re-enable and show the one selected in the current select:

```
$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
  $('.s').change(function() { //1
    $('.s option').prop('disabled',false);//enable all options //n
    $('.s option').show();//show all options //n
    $('.s option:selected').each(function(index){// disable and hide all of the current selected values from other select boxes //1  to select boxes n
        let value = $(this).val();
        $('.s option[value='+value+']').prop('disabled',true);//disable all with same value //select boxes n
        $('.s option[value='+value+']').hide();//hide them //select boxes n
        $(this).prop('disabled',false);//re-enable the current one //1
        $(this).show();//and show it //1
        $(this).prop('selected',true);//just to be sure re-select the option afterwards //1
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically update each select, you will need to do a few things:

1. Have a dynamic list in a data structure
2. Be able to figure out what is selected
3. Update (or recreate) the dropdowns when:

   - a selection is made *or*
   - a row is added *or*
   - a row is removed

This way you separate the view from the data backing it.

**Update:** Instead of re-rendering the options for each select, I toggle their "disabled" state.

```js
let rowId = 0;

const options = [
  { id: 1, name: "tan" },
  { id: 2, name: "lim" },
  { id: 3, name: "vin" },
  { id: 4, name: "alex" },
];

function getSelections() {
  return $('select.select2')
    .map((i, sel) => $(sel).val()).toArray()
    .map(id => parseInt(id, 10));
}

function fixSelections() {
  const selections = getSelections();
  $('select.select2').each((i, sel) => {
    let $sel = $(sel), val = $sel.val();
    $sel.find('option').each((j, opt) => {
      let $opt = $(opt);
      if ($opt.val() !== val && selections.includes(parseInt($opt.val(), 10))) {
        $opt.attr('disabled', true);
      } else {
        $opt.removeAttr('disabled');
      }
    });
  });
}

function populateOptions() {
  const selections = getSelections();
  return options.map(option => {
    return `
      <option value="${option.id}"
          ${selections.includes(option.id) ? 'disabled="disabled"' : ''}>
        ${option.name}
      </option>
    `;
  });
}

function addRow() {
  const tr = `
<tr class="cb" id="row_${rowId}">
  <td>
    <select class="s form-control select2" id="name1_${rowId}_first" name="name[]">
      ${populateOptions()}
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="number" name="winlose[]" id="amt1_${rowId}" class="form-control">
  </td>
  <td style="text-align:center">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger remove">-</a>
  </td>
</tr>
  `;
  rowId++;
  $('tbody').append(tr);
}

$('.addRow').on('click', function() {
  addRow();
  $('.s').change(function() {
    let value = $(this).val();
    $(this).siblings('.s')
      .children('option')
      .attr('disabled', false);
    $('.s').each(function() {
      $(this).siblings('.s')
        .children('option[value=' + $(this).val() + ']')
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    })
  });
  fixSelections();
});

$('tbody').on('click', '.remove', function() {
  $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  fixSelections();
});

$('.savebtn').on('click', function() {
  $('.listable .cb').each(function(index, item) {
    console.log($('#amt1_' + index).val());
  });
});

$(document).on('change', 'select.select2', e => fixSelections());
```

```css
option {
  color: #000;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  
}
option[disabled] {
  color: #777;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered listable">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th style="text-align:center"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info addRow">+</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="text-center"></tbody>
  </table>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary savebtn">Save</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Not really _need_

Comment: @user3647971 If you want a dynamic view, you need some type of model backing the view. The view should be able to re-create itself based on the state of data it is backed by.

Comment: @user3647971 I clarified my response so it does not sound like an ultimatum.

Comment: Well you can add custom event for change and bind a function to it and just fire that event in each of those events which require re-enabling or disabling options. So my argument stands that you don't _need_ all those things.

Comment: @user3647971 Instead of recreating, I could add a visibility state to each option instead. That way I just toggle them.

Comment: Might be better, all tho only disabling the option prevents it from being posted when a form is posted with that select. So if option is selected when disabling it would that unselect it or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: @user3647971 I went ahead and changed the behavior to toggle the "disabled" state of each option.

Comment: Actually a nice working example. A bit excessive on the syntax, but perfectly working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can perform this thing with **css** check snippet

```
option:checked { display: none; }
```

```css
option:checked { display: none; }
```

```html
<select>
<option>A for Alex</option>
<option selected>B for Billy</option>
<option>C for Cody</option>
<option>D for Danny</option>
</select>
```